# How to NOT autoconnect to bluetooth devices on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I am using a System76 laptop running Pop-OS (Ubuntu-based).

It is really annoying to me that every time my computer discovers a bluetooth device that it knows about, it automatically connects whether I want it to or not. I would much prefer to manually connect to devices when I choose to.

One case of this is with my Bluetooth audio adapter connected to speakers that I am likely not actually be in the same room with, or maybe I only want to pair them with my phone right now. I sometimes miss notifications because I don't know that they're coming through speakers in another room instead of from the built-in speaker that I might actually hear.

Currently, the only ways I can figure out to keep the computer from automatically connecting to a device are to turn off Bluetooth or forget the device, then having to go through the pairing process again next time I *do* want to connect.

I read some advice somewhere saying to install "blueman". I have done that, but after digging though its menus, I have not been able to figure out how that is supposed to help.